# No blank spaces in HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

Working on my code I found out a problem with one of the features for my project: Code preview.
I open a file with code inside it and reading all the lines I have an array with the lines.

This is the code:
Main.py

```
with open(path.join(files_folder, prj + '.' + file_ext)) as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
```

Then I use the lines variable in HTML:
index.html

```
<ol>
  {% for line in lines %}
    <li>{{ line }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Code inside the file:

```
while True:
    if 10 > 8:
        print('Hello World!')
```

The problem is, using print(lines) in Main.py file, it prints out the lines and the blank spaces but when i print it on HTML there aren't blank spaces.

P.S. I've tried also to print just line but it is equal as the lines print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, (repeated) spaces are ignored in HTML documents. If you want to show whitespace exactly as it is in the HTML source, use a `<pre>` tag or the `white-space: pre;` CSS style.

```html
<ol>
  {% for line in lines %}
    <li style="white-space: pre">{{ line }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/6dwzhs8b/

Comment: Thanks! @wander-nauta You've solved my problem! :D